# How can I search both plural and singular

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to search with "copiers" and "copier".
I want the same result in both case. can it is possible in sql server?

```
select * from Item where ItemName like '%copiers%'
```

Comment: what do you mean by *same result in both case*?

Comment: Woman/women is a bit tricky.

Comment: I want same result will come in both case "copier" and "copiers". mean same result for Plural and singular

Comment: You might want to look at full text searching which includes handling multiple different type of grammatical word variation.

Comment: can you give me any example link for this ?

Comment: it's a simple enough google search

Comment: This is not a simple situation which is why most search functions don't even attempt to handle this.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to set up [Full Text Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)

From that page:

> ... queries can search for any of the following:
>
> - One or more specific words or phrases (simple term)
> - A word or a phrase where the words begin with specified text (prefix term)
> - Inflectional forms of a specific word (generation term)
> - A word or phrase close to another word or phrase (proximity term)
> - Synonymous forms of a specific word (thesaurus)
> - Words or phrases using weighted values (weighted term)

I think "generation term" covers singular/plural.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution for Plural and singular case is the comparison in of data in both way like below,

```
SELECT * FROM Item WHERE ItemName LIKE '%copiers%'  OR 'copiers' LIKE '%'+ItemName+'%'
```

> 1. First compares `ItemName LIKE '%copiers%'`  to check ItemName is present in search string
> 2. Second compares `'copiers' LIKE '%'+ItemName+'%'` checks the search string contains ItemName

In both way you will get possible correct result